# Notebook Samsung NP910S5J compatibility with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to know if Ubuntu 14.04 will run on a Samsung NP910S5J notebook.

Comment: You can test Ubuntu using the LiveCD without risking an installation.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2):

The Samsung NP910S5J notebook is a one of the laptops in the Samsung Series 9. According to the official Ubuntu [Samsung Series 9](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SamsungSeries9) documentation:

> All essential features of Samsung Series 9 laptops work out of the box on Ubuntu 14.04.

You can also test if Ubuntu is compatible with your hardware by running Ubuntu from a live DVD or live USB without installing it on your hard drive. The hardware specifications of the Samsung NP910S5J notebook are well beyond the minimum systems requirements for Ubuntu 14.04. Here are the minimum systems requirements for Ubuntu 14.04.

- 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 1024 MB RAM
- Graphics processor and display capable of at least 1024x768
- 6 GB of disk space

It is recommended to have 2048 MB RAM to properly run Ubuntu desktop for day-to-day use.